# Proportion of straight red cards in European football

Tags: football, statistics

What are the statistics on the proportion of straight red cards that are shown in European leagues? That is, red cards that are shown immediately, rather than after two yellow cards.

Comment: Red cards can be shown after one yellow card, which is neither immediate nor after two yellow cards. Your wording does not fully describe the distinction you apparently want.

Answer (score 3):

[This *HowTheyPlay* article](https://howtheyplay.com/team-sports/Top-10-Most-Red-Cards-Premier-League) lists the number of straight red cards, and red cards after two yellows, for each Premier League season between 2009-10 and 2018-19.

| Season | 2 Yellows | Straight Reds | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009/10 | 27 | 30 | 57 |
| 2010/11 | 18 | 38 | 56 |
| 2011/12 | 21 | 37 | 58 |
| 2012/13 | 15 | 36 | 51 |
| 2013/14 | 14 | 39 | 53 |
| 2014/15 | 35 | 36 | 71 |
| 2015/16 | 25 | 34 | 59 |
| 2016/17 | 18 | 23 | 41 |
| 2017/18 | 18 | 21 | 39 |
| 2018/19 | 18 | 29 | 47 |

Straight red cards consistently make up **more than half** of all red cards. The exact proportion varies from season to season - straight reds made up 73.6% of all red cards in 2013/14, but just 50.7% the following season. On average, during those 10 seasons, straight reds make up **60.71%** of all red cards, or just over 3/5ths.

This is only the English Premier League; I don't know whether the proportion is similar in other European leagues.

Comment: Premier League football seems to be the most brutal in Europe :-)

Comment: @Bebs It's worth noting that the Premier League has 20 teams, more than most other top-level European leagues; there'll be more red cards in the Premier League by virtue of there being more matches per season.

Comment: Bundesliga is the only of the Fifth to have 18 teams. But I agree, Portugal, Netherlands and others have less than 20.